Electron window expands in width but does not retract
I am using electron to develop an app and I am sending an ipc message for expanding the app width and one for retracting it. There is the code, my frontend is triggering these ipc messages correctly, its just that it does not want to go back to 1024.
My app works with fixed widths and heights, when the retractAppView is in execution, it just moves the whole window 1px up.
// main.ts
ipcMain.on('expandAppView', () => {
    const mainWindow = BrowserWindow.getFocusedWindow()
    if (mainWindow) mainWindow.setSize(1400, 500, false)
})

ipcMain.on('retractAppView', () => {
    const mainWindow = BrowserWindow.getFocusedWindow()
    if (mainWindow) mainWindow.setSize(1024, 500, false)
})

// nav.tsx
let hasExpanded = false
const expandAppView = () => {
    if (!hasExpanded) window.electron.ipcRenderer.sendMessage('expandAppView')
    else window.electron.ipcRenderer.sendMessage('retractAppView')
    hasExpanded = !hasExpanded
}

// preload.ts
// Disable no-unused-vars, broken for spread args
/* eslint no-unused-vars: off */
import { contextBridge, ipcRenderer, IpcRendererEvent } from 'electron'

export type Channels = 'closeApp' | 'minimiseApp' | 'expandAppView' | 'retractAppView'

const electronHandler = {
    ipcRenderer: {
        sendMessage(channel: Channels, ...args: unknown[]) {
            ipcRenderer.send(channel, ...args)
        },
        on(channel: Channels, func: (...args: unknown[]) => void) {
            const subscription = (_event: IpcRendererEvent, ...args: unknown[]) =>
                func(...args)
            ipcRenderer.on(channel, subscription)

            return () => {
                ipcRenderer.removeListener(channel, subscription)
            }
        },
        once(channel: Channels, func: (...args: unknown[]) => void) {
            ipcRenderer.once(channel, (_event, ...args) => func(...args))
        },
    },
}

contextBridge.exposeInMainWorld('electron', electronHandler)

export type ElectronHandler = typeof electronHandler

I am expecting so that when the retractAppView ipc message runs, it makes the window 1024px wide

I found the solution, you must make your window resizable, then expand/retract the window size, then make it non-resizable
ex:
ipcMain.on('retractAppView', () => {
    const mainWindow = BrowserWindow.getFocusedWindow()
    if (!mainWindow) return

    mainWindow.resizable = true
    mainWindow.setSize(1024, 500, true)
    mainWindow.resizable = false
})

